# “Uninitialized use” warning in the g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, initialization

I’m using g++ with warning level `-Wall -Wextra` and treating warnings as errors (`-Werror`).

Now I’m sometimes getting an error “*variable* may be used uninitialized in this function”.

By “sometimes” I mean that I have two independent compilation units that both include the same header file. One compilation unit compiles without error, the other gives the above error.

The relevant piece of code in the header files is as follows. Since the function is pretty long, I’ve only reproduced the relevant bit below.

The exact error is:

> 'cmpres' may be used uninitialized in this function

And I’ve marked the line with the error by `*` below.

```
for (; ;) {
    int cmpres; // *
    while (b <= c and (cmpres = cmp(b, pivot)) <= 0) {
        if (cmpres == 0)
            ::std::iter_swap(a++, b);
        ++b;
    }
    while (c >= b and (cmpres = cmp(c, pivot)) >= 0) {
        if (cmpres == 0)
            ::std::iter_swap(d--, c);
        --c;
    }
    if (b > c) break;
    ::std::iter_swap(b++, c--);
}
```

(`cmp` is a functor that takes two pointers `x` and `y` and returns –1, 0 or +1 if `*x < *y`, `*x == *y` or `*x > *y` respectively. The other variables are pointers into the same array.)

This piece of code is part of a larger function but the variable `cmpres` is used *nowhere else*. Hence I fail to understand why this warning is generated. Furthermore, the compiler obviously *understands* that `cmpres` will never be read uninitialized (or at least, it doesn’t always warn, see above).

Now I have two questions:

1. **Why the inconsistent behaviour?** Is this warning generated by a heuristic? (This is plausible since emitting this warning requires a control flow analysis which is NP hard in the general case and cannot always be performed.)
2. **Why the warning?** *Is* my code unsafe? I have come to appreciate this particular warning because it has saved me from very hard to detect bugs in other cases – so this *is* a valid warning, at least sometimes. Is it valid here?

Comment: Just say `int cmpres = 0;` outside of the `for (; ;)` loop and get on with your life ;)

Comment: @Fred My issue is not to get the warning go away but to see whether the warning is actually *right* and I’m just too stupid to notice that there is an error in my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An algorithm that diagnoses uninitialized variables with no false negatives or positives must (as a subroutine) include an algorithm that solves the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  Which means *there is no such algorithm*.  It is *impossible* for a computer to get this right 100% of the time.

I don't know how GCC's uninitialized variable analysis works exactly, but I do know it's very sensitive to what early optimization passes have done to the code.  So I'm not at all surprised you get false positives only sometimes.  It does distinguish cases where it's certain from cases where it can't be certain --

```
int foo() { int a; return a; }
```

produces "warning: ‘a’ *is* used uninitialized in this function" (emphasis mine).

**EDIT:** I found a case where recent versions of GCC (4.3 and later) *fail* to diagnose an uninitialized variable:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    int a;
    return x ? a : 0;
}
```

Early optimizations notice that if `x` is nonzero, the function's behavior is undefined, so they *assume `x` must be zero* and replace the entire body of the function with "`return 0;`"  This happens well before the pass that generates the used-uninitialized warnings, so there's no diagnostic.  See [GCC bug 18501](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501) for gory details.

I bring this up partially to demonstrate that production-grade compilers can get uninitialized-variable diagnostics wrong both ways, and partially because it's a nice example of the point that undefined behavior can propagate backward in execution time.  There's nothing undefined about testing `x`, but because code control-dependent on `x` has undefined behavior, a compiler is allowed to assume that the control dependency is never satisfied and discard the test.

Comment: do you have a reference for your halting problem claim? I mean, I’ve stated the NP-hardness myself in the question (which would be compatible with that claim) but I’m less sure about your claim. The algorithm doesn’t actually have to solve the program flow, merely reconstruct it. – That said, interesting information about the wording of the warning.

Comment: ignore my question. It’s obvious: the compiler would have to prove total correctness (= finiteness of loops) which directly implies the Halting problem.

Answer (score 4):

There was an interesting discussion on clang dev-mailing list related to those heuristics this week.

The bottom line is: it's actually quite difficult to diagnose unitialized values without getting exponential behavior...

Apparently (from the discussion), gcc uses a predicate base approach, but given your experience it seems that it is not always sufficient.

I suspect it's got something to do with the fact that the assignment is mixed within the condition (and after a short-circuiting operator at that...). Have you tried without ?

I think both the gcc and clang folks would be very interested by this example since it's relatively common practice in C or C++ and thus could benefit from some tuning.

Comment: Aren't GCC and clang SSA compilers? An SSA compiler splits a variable in multiple variables according to the code paths on which it's used. In this case, an SSA compiler ought to have split `cmpres` in two for the two branches. In both branches, there's one read that follows the assignment.

Comment: @MSalters: the problem is that at the point you've reach the SSA form, it's difficult to map back to the "real" code I think when you have a diagnostic :/

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, but the compiler is failing to identify that the variable is never used without initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it's likely a heuristical error- that's what the "may" is for. I suspect that not many loop conditions look quite like that. That code is not unsafe because in all control paths, cmpres is assigned before use. However, I certainly wouldn't find it wrong to initialize it first.

You could, however, have some kind of variable shadowing going on here. That would be the only explanation I could think of for only one of the two translation units giving errors.

Comment: The point is, I would assume that *if* this is a heuristic and the compiler doesn’t always notice this, then the warning is actually justified (and points to a logic error), the compiler just doesn’t always notice it …