# Function which returns a reference to local object

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I've written a function which returns a reference to local object.

```
Fraction& operator*(Fraction& lhs, Fraction& rhs)
{
    Fraction res(lhs.num*rhs.num,lhs.den*rhs.den);
    return res;
}
```

After function return the res object will be destroyed and receiving object will point to Ex-Fraction object leading to undefined behavior on using it.
Anybody who is going to use this function will face problem.

Why does compiler can't detect this kind of situation as compile time error ?

Comment: Generally it can - g++ prints something like `warning: reference to local variable 'x' returned [enabled by default]`. It might depend on the compiler you are using and/or on the compiler switches you used.

Comment: that is what warnings are for, time to treat all warnings as error.

Comment: Note you can return by constant reference and it will be fine

Comment: GCC would produce something like `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘T&’ from a temporary of type ‘T’` with the appropriate flags.

Comment: GCC generates the warning mentioned above by default, except if you turn it off explicitly using `-Wno-return-local-addr`.

Comment: @user814628: No, returning a const reference to a local variable is just as bad.

Comment: Visual studio also detects this problem: `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary`

Comment: @interjay Yes you're right, my mistake

Comment: @yngum: The main issue with warnings is that most of them have false positives. One could argue that if the compiler cannot prove it's safe, then it should be forbidden, but since this would prevent new (dumb) compilers to enter the "market" it might actually stifle innovation. So instead, it's up to you to define a precise list of warnings that on which you trust the compiler. (for example of useless warnings, template code is generally interesting)

Comment: @MatthieuM. GCC is (rightly) conservative so `-Werror` usually works fine (and should be the default position). [So far I’ve encountered *one* warning which was genuinely wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4913254/1968) and needed to be worked around.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am not used to recent versions of gcc (still hung up on 4.3.2 at work...), but the ones I have worked with have some false positives with `-Wreturn`. Nothing an `UNREACHABLE` macro that unconditionally throw cannot solve, but still a bit annoying.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most compilers will show a warning when you do that. You should always turn warnings on with an option such as GCC's `-Wall`.

As for why an error isn't required by the Standard, it's because a function with flow control will make it difficult to tell whether the return value is referencing a local or not. (And undefined behavior only occurs if the return value is used by the caller.)

Comment: can you give an example for such "hard to tell" situation, without pointer arithmetic/creation?

Comment: @Elazar Sure, `return fn( local_var );` The function might return a reference to its argument, which is a local variable. Or `t &ref = flag? local : global;` and later `return ref;`. Then the compiler must prove that the function returns (as opposed to exit by exception) only if `flag` was `false`.

Comment: I think the compiler should emit a warning for the `return ref` pointing to the conditional expression. This is a "may" analysis. `return fn(local)` is a different story, I agree.

Comment: A situation where it would be much harder to detect: `const Foo& g(const Foo& arg); const Foo& f() { Foo local; return g(local); }`.  Whether `f` might return a local depends on what `g` does!

Comment: @aschepler That is what Potatoswatter already pointed out, you just renamed `fn` to `g` and `local_var` to `local` in his `return fn( local_var );`

Comment: @hvd: True. I somehow didn't properly read that comment when I "read" it.